# Enable acpi on Ubuntu 13.04 ARM ChromeBook

Tags: touchpad, acpi, chromebook

I've just recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 onto my Samsung ARM Chromebook, using http://chromeos-cr48.blogspot.com/2013/05/chrubuntu-one-script-to-rule-them-all_31.html, then upgraded to 13.10.

I'm having one problem with suspend, where all of the following will wake it from suspend:

1. Touching the touchpad
2. Closing the computer lid (this one is a bit problematic)
3. Touching any key on the keyboard

I found http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2088620, and tried to follow the directions involving `/proc/acpi/wakeup`, but the `/proc/acpi` directory doesn't exist.

The command `acpi_available` exits exit status 1, indicating that it ACPI is not available.

Ok, update here. I've gotten suspend practically fixed using a chromebook-snooze-hack package from the Chromebook ARM PPA. But the problem remains that there is no ACPI available.

My new goal here is to get ACPI enabled/available.

Comment: Since this is very hardware-specific, suggest you visit https://plus.google.com/communities/110512406501595697128/stream/c96f5e53-b9fb-4259-aefd-baad0405f698 and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/chromebook-central .

Comment: Using /proc to store ACPI information has been discouraged and deprecated since kernel 2.6.24. The same data is available in /sys. (I have this information from the Archlinux wiki)

Comment: @kiloseven I'll post there as well!

Comment: @Frank Is there a guide you know of that would tell how to use /sws instead of /proc for the wakeup?

Comment: @DaboRoss no idea, my earlier comment concerned only '/proc/acpi directory doesn't exist'; i've no experience on Ubuntu (neither on Archlinux) with suspend issues

Answer (score 0):

If ACPI is not installed, you can install it either by clicking [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/+package/acpi) or by running in a Terminal (use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>: `sudo apt-get install acpi`.

You'll then find the 'acpi' directory inside `/sys/` (if not, try in `/proc` too).

For rest of the solution, go ahead as given in the link you've already posted and update whether it works or not.

P.S. Another possible way to work with it is available [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromebook-central/PPQFpC7mYzk).

Comment: Using apt-get install acpi results in this: http://hasteb.in/raw/cagemuxema. Basically, no package available? I'll look at the link though

Comment: The package is available here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/+package/acpi

Comment: Doesn't seem to have an ARM version :/, I'm only seeing amd64 and i386

Comment: The acpi package is just utilities that work with active ACPI interfaces. They won't work if ACPI itself isn't active in the kernel. You would already need the `/sys/` and `/proc/` interfaces to use that package. Which would be impossible, in this circumstance, since the board itself doesn't support ACPI.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also running Ubuntu on my Samsung 3 Chromebook, and have been using it exclusively for about 6 months. While the ARM CPU instruction set is standardized, The ARM platform is extremely fragmented.  So platform standards, like those we use in x86, are often missing on any particular system.

So you're actually not experiencing unexpected behavior, ACPI is nonexistent on this board. 
Hence no /proc/acpi directory, and `acpi_available` returning exit status 1.  So to access what ACPI provided, it usually means you must access the hardware through the kernel drivers. For example, I found the battery charge status in the /sys/class directory.